# Configuring 'amq.rabbitmq.event' exchange to a different vhost?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I am configuring [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) with the [rabbitmq_event_exchange](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-event-exchange) plugin. I am using this plugin to listen to RabbitMQ [events](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-event-exchange#events). By default, the plugin is creating an exchange named 'amq.rabbitmq.event' in the default vhost(/) . But, I am trying to change vhost to 'test' (custom vhost created by me) As per the [instructions](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-event-exchange#configuration) from the plugin page, I added a property ***rabbitmq_event_exchange.vhost= test*** in my rabbitmq.conf file. But I am getting an exception when I try to run the RabbitMQ

```
    Config file generation failed 10:50:18.141 [error] You've tried to 
    set rabbitmq_event_exchange.vhost, but there is no setting with 
    that name.
    10:50:18.141 [error]   Did you mean one of these?
    10:50:18.176 [error]     mqtt.exchange
    10:50:18.176 [error]     log.exchange.level
    10:50:18.176 [error]     management.listener.port
    10:50:18.176 [error] Error generating configuration in phase 
    transform_datatypes
    10:50:18.176 [error] Conf file attempted to set unknown variable: 
    rabbitmq_event_exchange.vhost
```

My rabbitmq.conf file

```
    management.load_definitions= /opt/definitions.json
    #MQTT config
    mqtt.default_user= guest
    mqtt.default_pass= guest
    mqtt.allow_anonymous= false
    mqtt.exchange= MQTT
    mqtt.vhost= test

    #RabbitMQ event exchange config
    rabbitmq_event_exchange.vhost= test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin doesn't provide a new style configuration schema yet. I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-event-exchange/issues/31) in the plugin GitHub page to make this enhancement. We have to use the [advanced.config](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/master/docs/advanced.config.example) file and the classic config format to [configure](http://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html) the custom vhost.

**advanced.config**

```
[
  {rabbitmq_event_exchange, [{vhost, <<"test">>}]}
].
```

Ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/Z7_5WGc2ubE